# minimum size of a constructing set

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

> Let $ n $ be a positive natural number and let $ \mathbb N _ n = \{ 1 , \dots , n \} $. We call $ A $ a *constructing set* for $ \mathbb N _ n $ when $ A \subseteq \mathbb N _ n $ and for every $ a $ in $ A ^ { \mathrm c } $, there are $ b $ and $ c $ in $ A $ such that $ a = c - b $. For every positive natural number $ n $, find $ s _ n $, the minimum size of a constructing set for $ \mathbb N _ n $.

For $ n \le 29 $, I tried to find $ s _ n $ by brute force using a C program. The output was the following list of constructing sets:

$$ \begin {array} {|c|c|c|}
\hline
n & s _ n & \text {A Minimum-Sized Constructing Set for $ \mathbb N _ n $} \\
\hline
1 & 1 & \{ 1 \} \\
\hline
2 & 2 & \{ 1 , 2 \} \\
\hline
3 & 2 & \{ 2 , 3 \} \\
\hline
4 & 3 & \{ 2 , 3 , 4 \} \\
\hline
5 & 3 & \{ 3 , 4 , 5 \} \\
\hline
6 & 3 & \{ 2 , 5 , 6 \} \\
\hline
7 & 4 & \{ 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 \} \\
\hline
8 & 4 & \{ 3 , 6 , 7 , 8 \} \\
\hline
9 & 4 & \{ 3 , 7 , 8 , 9 \} \\
\hline
10 & 5 & \{ 4 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 \} \\
\hline
11 & 5 & \{ 4 , 8 , 9 , 10 , 11 \} \\
\hline
12 & 5 & \{ 4, 9 , 10 , 11 , 12 \} \\
\hline
13 & 5 & \{ 3 , 7 , 11 , 12 , 13 \} \\
\hline
14 & 6 & \{ 5 , 10 , 11 , 12 , 13 , 14 \} \\
\hline
15 & 6 & \{ 5 , 11 , 12 , 13 , 14 , 15 \} \\
\hline
16 & 6 & \{ 4 , 8 , 13 , 14 , 15 , 16 \} \\
\hline
17 & 6 & \{ 4 , 9 , 14 , 15 , 16 , 17 \} \\
\hline
18 & 7 & \{ 6 , 13 , 14 , 15 , 16 , 17 , 18 \} \\
\hline
19 & 7 & \{ 5 , 10 , 15 , 16 , 17 , 18 , 19 \} \\
\hline
20 & 7 & \{ 5 , 10 , 16 , 17 , 18 , 19 , 20 \} \\
\hline
21 & 7 & \{ 5 , 11 , 17 , 18 , 19 , 20 , 21 \} \\
\hline
22 & 7 & \{ 4 , 9 , 14 , 19 , 20 , 21 , 22 \} \\
\hline
23 & 7 & \{ 2 , 5 , 8 , 12 , 21 , 22 , 23 \} \\
\hline
24 & 8 & \{ 6 , 12 , 19 , 20 , 21 , 22 , 23 , 24 \} \\
\hline
25 & 8 & \{ 6 , 13 , 20 , 21 , 22 , 23 , 24 , 25 \} \\
\hline
26 & 8 & \{ 5 , 11 , 16 , 22 , 23 , 24 , 25 , 26 \} \\
\hline
27 & 8 & \{ 5 , 11 , 17 , 23 , 24 , 25 , 26 , 27 \} \\
\hline
28 & 8 & \{ 2 , 4 , 6 , 7 , 18 , 19 , 27 , 28 \} \\
\hline
29 & 8 & \{ 2 , 5 , 8 , 11 , 15 , 27 , 28 , 29 \} \\
\hline
\end {array} $$

Other than being increasing, I can't recognize a pattern to conjecture a formula for calculating $ s _ n $. Even I couldn't prove that $ ( s _ n ) _ { n = 1 } ^ \infty $ is increasing, so it may be wrong. Furthermore, the algorithm I used is not efficient and I couldn't come up with another algorithm that is not exponential-time.

My question is whether there is a formula for $ s _ n $ and an efficient systematic way to find a minimum-size constructing set for $ \mathbb N _ n $.

Comment: I think this may be http://oeis.org/A103298

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes! It is! In fact, the definitions are similar! These are related too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_ruler, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerfectRuler.html. Seems to be an open problem, or has it been solved and the pages are not up to date?

Comment: It seems that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_ruler contains what I wanted. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Good. Let me encourage you to write up what you have learned, and post it as an answer.